# How to get query params when I use <form> with POST method to trigger Firebase http functions?

Tags: firebase, httprequest, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to pass some query params to my http function in Firebase in a secure way. My params are not really sensitive like passwords, etc, they are some booleans, etc that determines logic server side.

When I try a simple `<form>` with method `GET` or `PUT` the `res.query` shows the values not when I use `POST`.

```html
  <form id="form" action="https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/myfuncName" 
   method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="test">
  </form>
```

I submit the form in Javascript by

```js
this.getElementById("form").submit();
```

in my function I have :

```js
function(req, res) {
    const param = req.query;
    console.log('query param is ' , param); //{} when form method is POST 
}
```

**I expect to be able to get id from res.query in my function but I get null {}. If I change method to GET or PUT then I see {id:test}.**

Any suggestion on enhancing the security of this would be appreciate too. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to handle this, and explain what exactly is not working the way you expect.

Comment: Did you try different enctype values? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: @TimMickey yes, just tried it with no luck. Tried all three variations 'text/plain" , 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , etc

Comment: @DougStevenson , added a bit more info, hope that makes it more clear. I am trying to find the most secure way to pass on some flags and keywords in my request to get an http function triggered and process, say, a payment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.query` allows you to get parameters coming from the query string of a request.  A POST request doesn't use the query string, so you can't use `res.query`.  POST sends parameters to the request body.

To access POST parameters in the request body that are coming form a form, you can use `req.body` as described in the [Cloud Functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had totally missed it. Any chance you have a recommendation for a secure way to send uid as a param with the request to http functions? I'm using the user.getIdToken() that is supposedly safe but not entirely sure.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to ask a separate question and explain in more detail what your security concern is.